# How to get value in the new line in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a code like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var tresc = " ";$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $('div').fadeTo('fast',1);
});
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $('div').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
});
$('#Generator_Nemuraj').click(function(){
    var val=$('input:radio[name=liczba]:checked').val();
    var tresc = "";         
    alert(val);
    $('#tekst').text(val);
    for (i=0;i<val;i++){
        var liczba1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        alert(liczba1);
        if (liczba1 <10){
            var liczba2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            alert('drugie losowanie koszyk 1'+' '+liczba2);
            if (liczba2<3){
                tresc2 = " text1"; 
                tresc = tresc + tresc2+'\n';
                $('#tekst').text(tresc);
            } else if (liczba2 <6){
                tresc3 = " text2";
                tresc = tresc + tresc3+'\n';
                $('#tekst').text(tresc);
            } else if (liczba2 <9){
                tresc4 = " text3";
                tresc = tresc+tresc4+'\n';
                $('#tekst').text(tresc);
            }
        } else if (liczba1<7){
            var liczba2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                alert('drugie losowanie koszyk 2'+' '+liczba2);                     
            } else {
            var liczba2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                alert('drugie losowanie koszyk 3'+' '+liczba2);                     
            }
    }
});
</script>
```

I want to print out resultat of this random generator like this:

text1
text2
text1... and so on

But in stead I get text1  text2  text1  text3...

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think you should use` <br />` tag instead of `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<br/>`:

```
 tresc = tresc + tresc3+'<br />';
```

And [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
 $('#tekst').html(tresc);
```

Comment: Worked :) I tried everything but haven tyhought of puting <br/> in ''.  Thnx once again